# restapi casha store data but i want when i click on listview item all items from service they store in cacha

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio

I apply cache but it works only one time when I click on first item it shows data after that when I click on another it shows same data how t fix it any guidelines
Here is my code

```
 String URL = "http://facekart.azanic.com/Data_show_all_.php";
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Fetcing, please wait...");
        progressDialog.show();
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");//getting array
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Itemssetget it = new Itemssetget();
                        it.setName(jsonObject1.getString("name"));
                        it.setPhonenumber_seller(jsonObject1.getString("phonenumber_seller"));

                        it.setPrice(jsonObject1.getString("price"));
                        it.setDiscountprice(jsonObject1.getString("discountprice"));
                        it.setUnits(jsonObject1.getString("units"));
                        it.setStock(jsonObject1.getString("stock"));
                        it.setId(jsonObject1.getString("key_auto"));
                        it.setImageurl("http://facekart.azanic.com/images/" + jsonObject1.getString("imageurl"));
                        if (it.getStock().toString().equals("In stock")) {
                            items_random.add(it);
                        }


                    }
                    if (!items_random.isEmpty() && getActivity() != null) {
                        myAdapter = new homebuyer_fruits_adapter(getActivity(), items_random, homebuyer.phone_number_shop);


                        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Random_list.addHeaderView(random_v);
                        Random_list.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                        Random_list.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
                        loadingdataprogress.stopShimmerAnimation();
                        loadingdataprogress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                        // Toast.makeText(getContext(),"ADDED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Some error occurred -> " + volleyError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ;
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                try {
                    Cache.Entry cacheEntry = HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response);
                    if (cacheEntry == null) {
                        cacheEntry = new Cache.Entry();
                    }
                    final long cacheHitButRefreshed = 3 * 60 * 1000; // in 3 minutes cache will be hit, but also refreshed on background
                    final long cacheExpired = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // in 24 hours this cache entry expires completely
                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    final long softExpire = now + cacheHitButRefreshed;
                    final long ttl = now + cacheExpired;
                    cacheEntry.data = response.data;
                    cacheEntry.softTtl = softExpire;
                    cacheEntry.ttl = ttl;
                    String headerValue;
                    headerValue = response.headers.get("Date");
                    if (headerValue != null) {
                        cacheEntry.serverDate = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
                    }
                    headerValue = response.headers.get("Last-Modified");
                    if (headerValue != null) {
                        cacheEntry.lastModified = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
                    }
                    cacheEntry.responseHeaders = response.headers;
                    final String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                            HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                    return Response.success(new String(jsonString), cacheEntry);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void deliverResponse(String s) {
                super.deliverResponse(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
                super.deliverError(error);
            }
            //adding parameters to send
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                parameters.put("s_number", homebuyer.phone_number_shop);
                parameters.put("trig", "all");
                return parameters;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        rQueue.add(request);
```

Thanks in advance if any one help  me in this I want every item click it shows data but first time it get from service second time it use from cache r any other method you can also suggest me How I smooth my app
I don't want to loading again and again